# Relative path does not apply correctly in page inspector of vs2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an xml data file stored in App_Data directory. I call the following method:

```
private string xmlPath = "/App_Data/Galery.xml";
private DataSet galery;

galery = new DataSet();
galery.ReadXml(xmlPath);
```

but when I browse the page from vs2012 I get the following error: File not found on "C:/App_Data/file.xml", although is should look for the file in the home directory of my app, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Szabolcs

Comment: And stylesheet included by <link href="App_LocalResources/Styles/ImageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" /> does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath solved the issue, if intelisense does not recognize it, use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath with system.web included.